# Is $C(K,S_t)$ a (local) martingale if PCS is broken?

Tags: implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, put-call-duality

When put-call symmetry holds
$$
P(S_t,K) = C(K,S_t) = \frac{K}{S_t} C \left( S_t, \frac{S_t^2}{K} \right)
$$
where $P$ is the market price of a put option and $C$ is the market price of a call option. The second equality above holds for homogeneous models which I am assuming.

Since $P(S_t,K)$ is a (local) martingale, so is $C(K,S_t)$, correct?

When PCS is broken then $P(S_t,K) \neq C(K,S_t)$, but is $C(K,S_t)$ nonetheless still a martingale or not anymore?